# Probability that a random variable is the k-th smallest

Tags: probability, order-statistics

Suppose we have random variables $X_1, \dots, X_n$ drawn independently from different distributions. How do we calculate the probability of some $X_i$ is the $k$th smallest of those random variables?

In other words (using order statistics notation), I want to calculate the following probabilities:

- Probability that $X_i$ is the smallest: $P(X_i = X_{(1)})$
- Probability that $X_i$ is the 2nd smallest: $P(X_i = X_{(2)})$
- ...
- Probability that $X_i$ is the $k$th smallest: $P(X_i = X_{(k)})$
- ...
- Probability that $X_i$ is the largest: $P(X_i = X_{(n)})$

Probability of smallest and largest seems easy enough. For example,
$P(X_1 = X_{(1)}) = \prod_{i=2}^n P(X_1 < X_i)$
due to independence.

But it gets more tedious after that. For any $k$, that means $k-1$ of the other random variables are less than $X_i$. There are ${n-1} \choose {k-1}$ possible choices for which ones those are. We could write an expression for the probability of each of the ${n-1} \choose {k-1}$ cases and then sum those probabilities, but that becomes a lot of expressions as $n$ grows.

Is there a more elegant way of calculating those probabilities other than evaluating all of those expressions?

---

If necessary, we can make the simplification that the variables are drawn from normal distributions with equal variance but different means, i.e., $X_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma^2)$. But ideally I'd like to solve for the general case when $X_i$ might come from a different (but known) distribution.

Comment: Short answer: nope.  It's tedious, even in the simplified case you describe at the end.

Comment: That's what I feared. Thanks!